# Custom sort hours and days

Tags: r, dplyr

I have text containing hours and days. I want to sort them in logical order - hours should appear first, then followed by days.

```
Time <- c("10 days ago", "9 days ago", "4 days ago", "2 days ago", "3 days ago", 
"6 days ago", "10 hours ago", "8 days ago", "5 days ago", "12 days ago", 
"8 hours ago")
```

Comment: Do you only have hours and days in your data?

Comment: yes i only have these two

Answer (score 3):

Here is one base R approach :

```
Time[order(match(sub('.*(hours|days).*', '\\1', Time), c('hours', 'days')), 
           as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', Time)))]

# [1] "8 hours ago"  "10 hours ago" "2 days ago"   "3 days ago"  
# [5] "4 days ago"   "5 days ago"   "6 days ago"   "8 days ago"  
# [9] "9 days ago"   "10 days ago"  "12 days ago"
```

We order data using two variables.

1. By hours and days.

   `sub` extracts either "hours" or "days" from `Time`, we use `match` to generate 1/2 as output. 1 given to hours and 2 to days.
2. By the number.

   We remove everything which is not a number from `Time` and convert it into numeric.

Comment: Thanks. I have this as a column in data.frame

Comment: It should not matter right? Instead of `Time` you use `df$column_name` ?

Answer (score 3):

These only use the base of R.

**1)** It creates a 3 column data frame with the three fields (`V1` is the number, `V2` is `hour` or `day` and `V3` is `ago`) and then performs the appropriate ordering with `V2` in descending order and within `V2` ordering `V1` in ascending order.  `order` produces an index which is applied to `Time`.

```
o <- with(read.table(text = Time), order(-xtfrm(V2), V1))
Time[o]
```

giving:

```
 [1] "8 hours ago"  "10 hours ago" "2 days ago"   "3 days ago"   "4 days ago"  
 [6] "5 days ago"   "6 days ago"   "8 days ago"   "9 days ago"   "10 days ago" 
[11] "12 days ago"
```

**2)** This is a variation of (1) that works since TRUE sorts after FALSE:

```
o <- with(read.table(text = Time), order(V2 == "days", V1))
Time[o]
```

**3)**  This one also uses the fact that TRUE sorts after FALSE.

```
o <- order(grepl("days", Time), as.numeric(sub(" .*", "", Time))
Time[o]
```